# Can't find what is wrong in the code?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to developed a simple regular expression program, but I keep getting this error from eclipse.

The error is in this line, in the non uppercase url

CharSequence getURLContent(URL url) throws IOException{

Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class VisualizaActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visualiza);


    String expr = "<td><span\\s+class=\"flagicon\"[^>]*>";

    CharSequence getURLContent(URL url) throws IOException{
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        String enconding  = conn.getContentEncoding();
        if (enconding == null){
            enconding = "ISO-8859-1";
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferredReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), enconding));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16384);
        try{
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
        } finally{
            br.close();
        }
        return sb;
    }


    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(expr,Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
            URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico");
            Matcher m = patt.matcher(getURLContent(url));
            while (m.find()) {
              String stateURL = m.group(1);
              String stateName = m.group(2);
              System.out.println(stateName + "," + stateURL);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to create a method within a method? Can Android do something I'm not aware of?

Comment: ^^ This. Your code is invalid. You can't do that.

Comment: @DaveNewton - it's like a `BufferedReader`, but colder.

Comment: @BrianRoach I figured it was pirated code, but I guess that's `BuffarrredReader`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't create a method inside a method. You tried to declare `getURLContent` inside `onCreate`